# Is the number of commutation classes of reduced words of the longest element of $S_n$ even for $n\geq 3$?

Tags: co.combinatorics, coxeter-groups

Observably, the number of primitive sorting networks on $n$ elements (or the number of commutation classes of reduced words of the longest element of $S_n$) is even for $3\leq n\leq 15$. These are all the values for which it has been computed so far. Is there an abstract way to see that it is always even?

Sequence is at http://oeis.org/A006245

Comment: Isn't it true for $n=2$ as well? Anyways, maybe you can show that a word $s_{i_1}s_{i_2}\cdots s_{i_k}$ and its reverse $s_{i_k}s_{i_{k-1}}\cdots s_{i_1}$ or twisted reverse $s_{n-i_k}s_{n-i_{k-1}}\cdots s_{n-i_1}$ never belong to the same commutation class.

Comment: @SamHopkins For $n=2$ the value is $1$. The reverse doesn't work because sometimes words are palindromic.

Comment: @SamHopkins Twisted reverse or conjugating the generators by the element might work. Have to think about that.

Comment: Ah sorry yes I got $n=2$ and $3$ mixed up. Good point about palindromes.

Comment: is there an oeis entry which is relevant here?

Comment: @PerAlexandersson I posted a link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the linked OEIS entry I find the following:

> Also the number of mappings X:{{1..n} choose 3}->{+,-} such that for any four indices a < b < c < d, the sequence X(a,b,c), X(a,b,d), X(a,c,d), X(b,c,d) changes its sign at most once (see Felsner-Weil and Balko-Fulek-Kynčl reference). - Manfred Scheucher, Oct 20 2019

There is an obvious fixed-point free involution on the set of such maps given by switching "+" and "-", assuming that $n \geq 3$ so that $\binom n 3 > 0$.